# How do you filter a date table based on two separate date filters in PowerBI?

Tags: date, filter, powerbi

I have 3 tables StartDateSelect EndDateSelect and Date.
Date is what is driving my other table in  the report.
[image]

Note Date3 is formatted as 123ABC to show "Latest" for the latest date after refresh else show Date. This is to make sure that for each scheduled refresh, I will always have the filters show as the latest date so the user doesn't have to switch it each day.

In my dashboard, I have two filters for date selection (start and End). I have selected the dates I want as shown:
[image]

I want the Dates table to be filtered for values BETWEEN the selected Start Date and Selected End Date (which in most cases will be stuck on "Latest")

I've played with filters on visuals and index columns with no luck, and I can't seem to get this to work. Or if there's another way to do this. The Between filter won't work with a word called "Latest" in it as it's ABC123 format by default.

Comment: Can you share a sample .pbix as the solution depends on how "Latest" is calculated.

Comment: Hi. I can explain how it goes. 
I duplicate the Date table and call it startDateSelected
I add a column called Dates2 in power query Table.Max(Date, "Dates")
then I add another column called Dates3 if [Dates2] = [Dates] then "Latest" else [Dates]
the max date in the date table will always be the latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a measure as follows.

```
Measure = 
VAR cursor = MAX('Date'[Dates])
VAR startDate = MAX(StartDatesSelect[Dates])
VAR endDate = MAX(EndDateSelect[Dates])

RETURN IF(cursor IN DATESBETWEEN('Date'[Dates], startDate, endDate),1,0)
```

Set a filter on your visual as follows:

[image]

That's it.

[image]

Comment: Great thank you! I'll mark this as a solution because it works for the problem as I've asked it. It works on my end. I am however having difficulty with incorporating this into a dashboard with bar graphs from the table which date is controlling. ex) datecontrolls-> table2[itemdate, Item, attr1, attr2...]. the bar graph would be simply xaxis = attr1 and yaxis = count(item). I'll apply the filtermeasure above as a filter visual , but It seems like the bar graph goes blank when I select dates.  Just doesn't seem to be functioning 100%

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing a .pbix